# how to create a VS2015 project inside a specific directory with a specific projectname?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Not sure how to describe my question and ok here it goes:

We already have some existing projects created and under TFS source control.
A typical project is then stored locally as:

SomeDir\SomeNameSpace.SomeName\ProjectName\
then the csproj and sln file inside that directory will be named: SomeNameSpace.SomeName.ProjectName

Now when I want to create that same setup using Visual Studio it goes horribly wrong:

I have tried all possible options on creating a project and either it creates an extra SomeNameSpace.SomeName.ProjectName folder extra under the ProjectName directory and puts the sln and csproj inside that dir or I can create a Project under the proper ProjectName dir only then the name of the sln and csproj files will be ProjectName.snl/csproj which is neither what I want.

Renaming them of course would be the logical thing to do, however, doing that causes the sln to go corrupt. When I try to reopen it will throw a Save as DevEnv.sln in my face and that is not what I want.

Edit: Of course I have renamed inside the sln and csproj file which neither led me to the solution

So how can I create a new VS2015 solution that will nicely sit under 
    \SomeDir\SomeNamespace.SomeName\ProjectName\ with 
    SomeNameSpace.SomeName.ProjectName.sln and
    SomeNameSpace.SomeName.ProjectName.csproj as it's name?

What am I missing, that it seems impossible to achive this in a simple manner?

Comment: Create the project the normal way, then move it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I am sure I have tried that as well.. guess the solution itself doesn't pick up the move correctly and then becomes corrupt again..

Comment: @Dutchman078 you can always fix names if you know how .sln and .csproj files work.

Comment: @Mafii, so what you are suggesting is creating the project with name ProjectName under SomeDir
(what will give me the directory structure I want) and then just edit it inside csproj and sln, to be NameSpace.SomeName.ProjectName instead of ProjectName it already was?

Comment: Ok, let me clarify my suggestion : create the project the normal way.  Remove it from the solution.  Move it, add it back to the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok we have figured it out.
The solution as posted by A. Chiesa was almost right.

The solution, projects and namespaces need to be set.
 - Rename the Solution within the "Solution Explorer" for example name it "NameSpace.SomeName.ProjectName"
 - Rename the Project within the "Solution Explorer" for example also name it "NameSpace.SomeName.ProjectName"
 - Go to the project properties and rename within Application the "Assembly name:"  for example also name it "NameSpace.SomeName.ProjectName"
 - Go to the project properties and rename within Application the "Default namespace:"  for example also name it "NameSpace.SomeName.ProjectName"

Then if you are lucky, you can use Resharper to rename the namespace for all files throughout your project or you have to do it manually (depending on files count can be a very tedious job to do).

That should do it.

Thanks everyone for your input and advice.

Best regard,

Ed

Answer (score 4):

Create the Project from the New Project VS Window. The settings you need are:

- Name: ProjectName
- Do NOT create directory for solution

This should create the csproj and sln files in the appropriate directory.

From here, right clic on the project in Solution Explorer -> Rename -> SomeNameSpace.SomeName.ProjectName

This way, the solution reference will be updated too.

Now, rename the solution too, from Solution Explorer.

File menu, Save All. This saves both the project AND the solution.

And I think that's it.

Comment: Somehow that doesn't work (have tried it of course) problem is when you close your solution, it asks if you want to save, which of course I did. Then on reopening the solution it will give me the DevEnv.sln notification... Cancelling that will open the solution, I think you agree with me, it's not the right solution to my problem.

Comment: Did you do a File->Save All, by chance? If you don't, neither project nor solution will be saved, and you can corrupt things.

Comment: Hmm I am not sure, by default when I change something I do a ctrl+s after changing something..

According to my colleague (and my rather pissed of manager) you also have to change the default namespace on the project properties on the Application Tab. Then for each file in the solution (luckily we have Resharper) you have to change the namespace as well.

Comment: Please note that Ctrl-S doesn't save the project if you haven't selected it in Solution Manager. I just checked this on VS 2013 Community. It works as I described. I don't get the "change the namespace for each file in the solution": maybe it can be a related question, but if your namespace convention is consistent you should be able to limit your changes to the default namespace in your project, which should match the namespace assigned to the files in the root dir of your project. Subdirectories should match subnamespaces by name.

Answer (score 1):

You should in your new project window have it look like this
[image: Solution in same folder as project]

Please note the highlighted aria is unticked

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to make a screenshot etc. I of course know how to make a project and have tried various options that are possible. None of them leading to what I want or at least by still having a working solution. (DevEnv.sln when it somehow corrupts)

Comment: What structure are you after
-Dev
--SomeNameSpace
---*.sln
---ProjectName
---*.csproj

or

-Dev
--SomeNameSpace
---*.sln
--*.csproj
---ProjectName